# Angular 2: cannot access filters or attribute-properties in expression

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2 and I have got a serious question about expressions. When i put a simple expression like {{2+2}} into my template, it works. I see the digit "4" displayed on my screen. But whenever I try to do something more complicated in an expression, it fails.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'timos-app',
  template: `
   <form>
      <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='pizza'>
      <p>
       You are looking for: {{ pizza.length }}
    </p>
    </form>
  `
})
export class PizzaApp {
}
```

So, i want to display the text "You are looking for:" and then the length
of the word written in the input box. But it doesn't even show "You are looking for:". Only when I change "pizza.length" into "pizza" it shows me the word I wrote into the box.

I hope you can answer my question,
Thank you!

Ok, with the questionmark-operator the solutions works. But now I got another problem. I can't use pipes in expressions. I copied a simple example from the official Angular-website, but it doesn't work. The screen is empty when I run it.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'timos-app',
    template: `<div>
    <p>A: {{a | currency:'USD':false}}</p>
    <p>B: {{b | currency:'USD':true:'4.2-2'}}</p>
</div>`
})
export class PizzaApp {
  a: number = 0.259;
  b: number = 1.3495;
}
```

Comment: Try the expression {{pizza?.length}}. Or intialize pizza in the component.

Comment: Thank you, it works with the question mark. Can you tell me why? I never saw it in a tutorial.

Comment: the simplest way would be to initialize pizza field with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Elvis operator because `pizza` is undefined at the beginning:

```
You are looking for: {{ pizza?.length }}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/39yQjbWN64o0kBFgPEHR?p=preview.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 2 documentation states:

> The Angular Elvis operator (?.) — perhaps better described as the
>   "safe navigation operator" — is a fluent and convenient way to guard
>   against null and undefined values in property paths.

So, when you just have:

```
<p>
       You are looking for: {{ pizza.length }}
</p>
```

JS throws a null reference error (so does Angular). Using Elvis operator (?):

```
  <p>
           You are looking for: {{ pizza?.length }}
  </p>
```

your view renders fine and displaying:  You are looking for: (without length, since pizza is not initialized yet).

Comment: Pipes works for me. As I can see you have selector name:  selector: 'timos-app', change it to my-app, and PizzaApp into AppComponent. But it would be good for you to try understand child-parents relationship between components.